# JOB LINQ para atualizar valores no Banco de dados!

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Eu tenho um JOB no qual preciso atualizar todos os valores para o valor máximo que existe pra uma coluna, mas meu código não está funcionando.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Meu código:

```C#
List<SqlOnlyCostModel> costat = new List<SqlOnlyCostModel>();
foreach (var QuantityItem in all)
{
    int maxQtd = all.Max(x => x.QuantityItem);
    decimal maxPrice = all.Max(x => x.UnitPrice);
    string nCurrency = all.Max(x => x.Currency);
    string nCost = all.Max(x => x.Currency);
}

_dbEngContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Lucas, traduza sua pergunta para português!

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que você esteja utilizando um Model para esses valores atribuídos, seria algo como:

```
//Your code
Context.Entry(ModelName).State = EntityState.Modified;
Context.SaveChanges();
```